# Linear hall sensor to detect large fields with digital output?

Tags: microcontroller, hall-effect

For an application I need to measure magnetic fields in the range between -200mT to +200mT with sub-mT resolution. Additionally a microprocessor is available but I don't have a high resolution ADC and want to avoid sensing low voltages in a noisy laboratory environment if possible.

Are there Hall sensors available that have a serial, I2C or similar output with at least 12 bit resolution in the field range given above?

An additional caveat: this is a beginner's one-off project, so I want to avoid sensors that require an custom EEPROM programmer or other expensive items. In principle something like the TLE4998S from Infineon but without a custom protocol and $600 evaluation kit.

Answer (score 1):

If you can drop the digital interface requirement, allegro makes a line of linear hall effect sensors that are very inexpensive and readily available. they do have a number of digital options as well, but I haven't used them:

http://www.allegromicro.com/en/Products/Magnetic-Linear-And-Angular-Position-Sensor-ICs/Linear-Position-Sensor-ICs/A1324-5-6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1 Gauss=0.1 mTesla, so you're looking at a span of about 2V if you find a sensor that puts out 0.5mV/Gauss.  I don't think you need to be overly concerned about ADC resolution.  10bits will give you 5mV res over a 5V range, which will be about a tenth of a mTesla, even without amplification.  A built in ADC will likely do the job.